# How to compensate an op-amp at a particular frequency?

Tags: operational-amplifier, compensation

I am trying to design an op-amp but because it is going to be used at a max frequency of 10kHz, I only need to make sure the phase margin is good enough at this frequency. Most of the methods for designing op-amps that I found compensate the op-amp for the worst case scenario which is when it used as a buffer. However, in my case, it will never be used as a buffer. Is there a method I can follow that shows how to design an op-amp that is compensated at a particular frequency ?

Please see an image of the circuit: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8d4Y.jpg

The maximum frequency the input signal is 10kHz. The high-pass circuit sets the closed-loop gain at 40dB.

Comment: Start with the open loop bode plot.

Comment: Frequency compensation generally is thought to serve the amplifier the expected stability when a negative feedback network is applied - not just for a 'buffer' configuration. That's why you don't compensate for *one* frequency, which honestly doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: The stability margin (phase margin) does not only depend on the frequency range you intend to work with. You also must specify the mimnimum closed-loop gain for your application.

Comment: The signal you care about may be at 10kHz, but if it starts oscillating madly at 500kHz you'll care -- so it needs to be compensated for the whole frequency band.

Comment: Your question is too broad.  Could you **edit your question** to tell us what voltage gain you want, and whether its inverting or not?  Perhaps show us *your candidate circuit*?  Most modern op-amps come pre-compensated and stay stable in most op-amp circuits.  Unless you need super speed or super precision, or are asking for super-high gain, chances are great that you're fine just whipping up a cookbook solution.

Comment: @TimWescott, I have edited my post.

Comment: The picture seems to indicate that you are building the op-amp in silicon.  Is this the case, or are you using an off-the-shelf op-amp?  You're also showing a circuit that has a capacitive load on the inverting input.  Is that so?  If so, and if you're using an off-the-shelf compensated opamp then the frequency \$f = 1/(2 \pi R_f C_f)\$ needs to be less (I'd go at least four times less) than the GBW product of the amp.  If you're rolling your own amp in silicon then you pretty much need to know how to do the calculations yourself.

Comment: Yes - as mentioned by Tim Wescott - it is absolutely not clear what you are going to do. "Designing an opamp" ? Or designing an amplifier using an existing opamp ?

Answer (score 0):

If an amplifier is inadequately compensated it may oscillate even with no input signal applied.

Plot loop gain (open loop and feedback network combined) and phase and adjust the compensation capacitor's value to make sure that the loop gain gets down below 1 well before the loop phase reaches -180 degrees, (say 50 degrees before.) This should then give stability when the loop is subsequently closed.

Usually such a high value of closed loop gain would give you a big advantage of being able to compensate for a high bandwidth. (With a lower beta open loop gain can be higher giving increased bandwidth).  But high bandwidth is not important to you. So with a beta of 1/100 you can compensate for an unusually high phase margin giving very good stability and not worry about the reduced bandwidth that results.

But bear in mind that the bigger the required phase margin, the lower the open loop gain will need to be (for any particular beta) and the lower the feedback factor (1 + B.Aol) will be resulting in reduced performance such as higher distortion levels.

So it is a compromise between stability and performance.

beta, B = 1/(Noise Gain)